# How to add drag-to-edge overflow div scrolling behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am using HTML5 Drag and Drop API to reorganize elements in a vertical list. The list is an `overflow-y: scroll` div. On macOS Chrome and macOS Firefox, if an item is dragged very close (~20px) to the inside edge of the container, the container is scrolled. This behaviour is not present on macOS Safari.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wh91g2cb/)

I am interested in how to implement a modified version of this behaviour for all modern browsers:

- How to have a larger scroll activation region. On macOS Chrome it must be inside the container and is relatively small (20px). Preferably it could be increased to something like 15% of the container height.
- Preferably the region would remain *inside the list* (so if you scroll outside the list the container is not scrolled)
- How to disable the apparently undocumented Chrome scrolling behaviour. (Assuming it isn't possible to "enable" this feature on Safari, Edge).

Constraints:

- A raw JavaScript / html / css solution is acceptable
- I am using React, so a React library that works with raw JS HTML5 Drag n Drop would also be acceptable
- No jQuery

Edit: Updated browser support description, updated JSFiddle to support macOS Firefox.